# How to return a string starting from specified character? Javascript

Tags: javascript, substring, indexof

I have to create a function that searches for the first occurrence of the character c (an unsigned char) in the string pointed to by the argument str. The terminating null character is considered to be part of the string.

**So i did this:**

```
function my_strchr(str, c){
return str.substring(c.length + str.indexOf(c));
}
```

But it returns a string without c character. For example, input is "abcabc" && b.
Expected output is bcabc, but I have cabc. Could anybody help?

Comment: Why are you adding the `c.length` ? If you remove that, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

make it like this and it should be okay

`return str.substring(str.indexOf(c));`

it will start from the index of C till the end of `str`

check

> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

to know more about the `substring()`